# Grails UrlMapping 404

Tags: grails, groovy, url-mapping

I have this:

```
static mappings = {
   "/a/b/$id/stuff"(controller: "stuff", action "action1" )
   "/a/b/$id/stuff/$stuffId"(controller: "stuff", action "action2" )
   "/a/b/$id/stuff/$stuffId/c"(controller: "stuff", action "action3" )
}
```

I can hit `action1` and `action2`, but I can't hit `action3`, as it returns a `404`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def method(){

}
```

will not work.

```
def method = {


}
```

WILL work.

Comment: Tip: use the codenarc grails plugin.  It has a rule to catch this mistake, plus many other rules of varying usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the code of your view? I guess if it can't compile, you'll get a 404.
At least, that's what I experienced.